# How does Ubuntu 18.04 "support emojis"?

Tags: 18.04, emoji

What does it mean Ubuntu 18.04 will "support colored emojis"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Ubuntu 18.04 show filenames containing emojis in colour?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102715/does-ubuntu-18-04-show-filenames-containing-emojis-in-colour)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are quoting this [OMG Ubuntu article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/11/ubuntu-finally-long-last-time-support-color-emoji).

Ubuntu (18.04) "supports colored emojis" means you'll be able to see system-wide coloured emojis out-of-the box, not just in some specific applications.

Currently in Ubuntu 17.10 or older versions you get to see coloured emojis without any extra modifications in for example, Firefox:

[image]

But the same emojis may render as simple monochromatic line drawings in other applications, e.g. gEdit:

[image]

Even though GNOME 3.26 (default in Ubuntu 17.10) supports coloured emojis, it's actually a missing feature in Ubuntu 17.10 as some necessary packages, which are `fontconfig` v2.12.5, `cairo` v1.15.7, and a font that supports coloured emojis are missing ([source](https://trello.com/c/FVcXa6l7/21-color-emoji-support)).

This will be fixed in Ubuntu 18.04 and you'll be able to see coloured emojis everywhere out-of-the-box, as well as having a nice system picker application for choosing them.

Comment: If you want to get rid of it: `sudo apt purge --autoremove fonts-noto-color-emoji`

Comment: @JanKatins Thank you. Ubuntu's 19.04 minimal setup does not include this package