# Does Ubuntu 18.04 show filenames containing emojis in colour?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, emoji

I've recently transferred some files made on Mac OS, and containing emojis in their filename, to my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine.

The emojis show up in Nautilus, albeit monochromatic. Will I see them in full color if I switch to 18.04 LTS?

Comment: Related: [How does Ubuntu 18.04 “support emojis”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022342/how-does-ubuntu-support-emojis)

Comment: @Fabby The two questions are duplicates of each other, but this question should be left open and the direction of the duplication should be reversed so that the other question is a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @karel: the other question is older and that is the direction we normally take..  Close vote retracted while you take time responding..  **;-)**

Comment: I chose the direction with the better answers regardless of who posted first. In this case there was some doubt, so I tested the answers before voting. I don't want Ask Ubuntu users to be frustrated like I often am at Stack Overflow where I test ten answers and none of them work, so I have to stop wasting time and debug my own malfunctioning code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tested this out in a VM, and it seems you can get colour emojis in 18.04:

1. 16.04:

   [image]
2. 18.04:

   [image]

The filenames were created over ssh from macOS using `touch` ; the emojis entered using the macOS emoji picker.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, 18.04 supports colour emoji by default.

> The Ubuntu desktop now ships with a full set of color emoji. Previously, emoji support was inconsistent and emojis appeared as black-and-white in some applications.

Source: [What’s New in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS “Bionic Beaver” - How to Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/350011/whats-new-in-ubuntu-18.04-lts-bionic-beaver-available-now/)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, I've made today a 18.04 LTS clean install: the emojis that looked monochromatic on 16.04 now look fully coloured. There are just some minor differences between the Apple and SVG emojis sets.